# WordPress Getting Data Only Selected Date Range

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am making a villa rental website for my client.

I am using wordpress theme named Easybook.

However, there is a logical error here. I'm choosing a date range when filtering villas. For example, when I select a date between 14-19, if at least one day is empty between these dates, it brings the villa.

However, what I want is to bring only the completely empty villas for 14-19 dates. In other words, if the dates 14-15-16-17-18-19 are available, it should show the results.

I hope I was explanatory. Thanks.

Website link: https://tatilhomes.com/

most likely the filtering code is as follows

```
<?php
/* add_ons_php */

//$azp_attrs,$azp_content,$azp_element
$azp_mID = $el_id = $el_class = $azp_icon = $title = $filter_dis =''; 

// var_dump($azp_attrs);
extract($azp_attrs);

$classes = array(
    'azp_element',
    'azp_filter_date',
    'azp-element-' . $azp_mID, 
    $el_class,
);
// $animation_data = self::buildAnimation($azp_attrs);  
// $classes[] = $animation_data['trigger'];
// $classes[] = self::buildTypography($azp_attrs);//will return custom class for the element without dot
// $azplgallerystyle = self::buildStyle($azp_attrs);

$classes = preg_replace( '/\s+/', ' ', implode( ' ', array_filter( $classes ) ) ); 

if($el_id!=''){
    $el_id = 'id="'.$el_id.'"';
}
// var_dump($filter_dis);
$checkin_get = isset($_GET['checkin']) ? $_GET['checkin'] : '';
$checkout_get = isset($_GET['checkout']) ? $_GET['checkout'] : '';
$default_value = !empty($checkin_get) && !empty($checkout_get) ? esc_attr( $checkin_get ).';'.esc_attr( $checkout_get ) : 'current';
?>
<div class="<?php echo $classes; ?>" <?php echo $el_id;?>>
    <?php if ($filter_dis == 'listing'): ?>
        <!-- col-list-search-input-item -->
        <div class="col-list-search-input-item in-loc-dec date-container  fl-wrap">
            <div class="cth-daterange-picker"
                data-name="checkin" 
                data-name2="checkout" 
                data-format="<?php _ex( 'DD/MM/YYYY', 'Date range picker format', 'easybook-add-ons' ); ?>" 
                data-default="<?php echo esc_attr( $default_value ); ?>"
                data-label="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>" 
                data-icon="<?php echo $azp_icon;?>" 
                data-selected="slot_date"
            ></div>


                

        </div>
        <!-- col-list-search-input-item end -->
    <?php elseif($filter_dis == 'header'): ?>
        <div class="header-search-input-item fl-wrap date-parent"> 
            <div class="cth-daterange-picker"
                data-name="checkin" 
                data-name2="checkout" 
                data-format="<?php _ex( 'DD/MM/YYYY', 'Date range picker format', 'easybook-add-ons' ); ?>" 
                data-default="<?php echo esc_attr( $default_value ); ?>"
                data-label="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>" 
                data-icon="<?php echo $azp_icon;?>" 
                data-selected="slot_date"
            ></div>
        </div>
    <?php else: ?>
        <div class="main-search-input-item main-date-parent main-search-input-item_small fl-wrap">
            <div class="cth-daterange-picker"
                data-name="checkin" 
                data-name2="checkout" 
                data-format="<?php _ex( 'DD/MM/YYYY', 'Date range picker format', 'easybook-add-ons' ); ?>" 
                data-default="<?php echo esc_attr( $default_value ); ?>"
                data-label="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>" 
                data-icon="<?php echo $azp_icon;?>" 
                data-selected="slot_date"
            ></div>
        </div>
    <?php endif ?>
</div>
```

Comment: It's hard to give more structured advice here as it's unclear how you're making the query. But the logic you have to put into the query is `AND`. If it's SQL... Then villa is empty on 14, AND villa empty on 15 AND.... You're query is currently OR.

Comment: hello, thanks for answer i was added code block on my question. can you review it again?